# Geom_dotplot is showing extra points that don't appear in my dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dotplot of continuous y data over several days presented as a dotplot and the number of points per group evolves over time and somehow on the last day some extra points are created.

My first idea was to make check the table in order to verify the amount of points per day and everything was correct.

```
        ggplot(aes(x=Days,y= value,fill=Animal_type,color=Animal_type))+
geom_dotplot(color="black",
             binaxis = "y",
             stackdir = "center",

             alpha=0.2,aes(group=interaction(Days,Animal_type)))+

scale_y_continuous() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(axis_x))+
scale_color_manual(values = c("black","#E50914","grey"),
                   aesthetics = c("color","fill"))+

stat_summary(fun.y = "median", fun.args = list(mult = 1),
             geom="line",
             aes(x=Days,y=value,color=Animal_type,group=Animal_type),
             size=1)+

theme_classic()+

theme(aspect.ratio = 1,
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
      strip.text = element_text(size = 11),
      strip.background = element_blank(),
      strip.placement = "outside")+#function to change the appearance of the axis

labs(y=" ",
     x="Time(Days)",
     color="Animal type",
     fill="Animal type")+

facet_wrap(variable~., scales = "free",strip.position = "left",labeller =as_labeller(c("WBC 10^9/l"="10^9 cells/l","RBC 10^12/l"="10^12 cells/l","Platelets 10^9/l"="10^9 cells/l")))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U7Rf.jpg
this is the graph I get and at day 27 there too many points for animals of the group "Conventional" ,there 6 instead of 3
if you look at the data frame these points don't exist (these are the values for day 27 for the 2 first graphs):

```
               Sample.ID         variable  value  Animal_type Days    Cell_type
    1       1072       WBC 10^9/l  16.45 Conventional   27       WBC
   2       1073       WBC 10^9/l  25.97 Conventional   27       WBC
   3       1074       WBC 10^9/l  18.20 Conventional   27       WBC
   4       1075       WBC 10^9/l  17.26          SPF   27       WBC
   5       1076       WBC 10^9/l  19.97          SPF   27       WBC
   6       1077       WBC 10^9/l  14.78          SPF   27       WBC
   7       1078       WBC 10^9/l  24.55          SPF   27       WBC
   8       1079       WBC 10^9/l  17.06          SPF   27       WBC
   9       1080       WBC 10^9/l  15.18          SPF   27       WBC
   10      1081       WBC 10^9/l  16.57 Conventional   27       WBC
   11      1082       WBC 10^9/l  15.24 Conventional   27       WBC
   12      1083       WBC 10^9/l  16.80 Conventional   27       WBC
   13      1072      RBC 10^12/l   6.44 Conventional   27       RBC
   14      1073      RBC 10^12/l   2.80 Conventional   27       RBC
   15      1074      RBC 10^12/l   5.91 Conventional   27       RBC
   16      1075      RBC 10^12/l   6.75          SPF   27       RBC
   17      1076      RBC 10^12/l   6.67          SPF   27       RBC
   18      1077      RBC 10^12/l   6.84          SPF   27       RBC
   19      1078      RBC 10^12/l   3.88          SPF   27       RBC
   20      1079      RBC 10^12/l   6.64          SPF   27       RBC
   21      1080      RBC 10^12/l   6.58          SPF   27       RBC
   22      1081      RBC 10^12/l   6.86 Conventional   27       RBC
   23      1082      RBC 10^12/l   3.33 Conventional   27       RBC
   24      1083      RBC 10^12/l   5.99 Conventional   27       RBC
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? For both cells/l groups there are 6 values for each Animal_type in your table. The same as in your plot.

Comment: no as you can see in each variable there only 3 for Conventional and 6 for SPF

Comment: For the 10^9 group there are 6 Conventional entries. The same for the 10^12 group.

Comment: If these are not your groups of interest you need to be more precise. In the data you posted there are overall 12 entries for SPF and 12 for Conventional, divided among two groups making it 6 entries per groups.

Comment: I thank you so much for your help, I had not seen them (difficult day). This is not my data, I talked to the people and they actually ran some samples twice and added a "run2" in the sample name which I have to take instead of the first one. This is going to take some time.